# Find first occurrence of a string after the first occurrence of another string with bash

Tags: awk, grep

I have an input file that looks like this and i want the first occurrence of words but only after the first occurrence of special

## The numbers are only there so i know i got the right string

EDIT: I realized that it matters the strings have /'s

```
words/and/stuff #1
words/more #2
some/other/words #3
special/this #1
words/i/need/you/i.really.need.you #4
special/cool #2 
words/random #5
```

Im trying to find the first occurrence of "word" after i find the first occurrence of "special"

The output should be

```
words/i/need/you/i.really.need.you #4
```

Ive tried the following

```
grep -m1 special file | grep -m1 words file 

awk 'NR==1,/special/ && NR==1,/words/ {print $0}' file
```

Comment: You nearly had it... `grep -A 99999 special file | grep -m1 words`

Comment: @MarkSetchell WOW!!!! Thats simple and straight forward!!!!! Ill end up using that.

Comment: Im learning how ignorant it is to make simulated input files. I will start putting the literal input file to avoid headaches on both parties. This is actually for a xml file and that grep command returns both greps not just the latter one but i can solve it from there it may be a little redundant. But ill play with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$ awk '/special/{f=1} f && /words/ {print; exit}' file 
words/i/need/you/i.really.need.you #4
```

How it works:

- `/special/{f=1}`

  If the current line matches `special` then set variable `f` to `1`
- `f && /words/ {print; exit}`

  If `f` is non-zero and the current line matches `words`, then print the current line and exit.

#### Words with slashes

If the word you want to match is not merely surrounded by slashes but includes them, the same code works.  It is just necessary to escape the slashes.  For example, if we are looking for the word `words/i/need`  after `special`:

```
$ awk '/special/{f=1} f && /words\/i\/need/ {print; exit}' file 
words/i/need/you/i.really.need.you #4
```

Comment: Terribly sorry realized later i have /'s that affect the code

Comment: @goosegoose  Thanks for the notice.  With the updated input file,  the same code here still works.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
$0=="words"{
  count++
  if(special_count==1){
    print "String words count is: "count
    exit
  }
}
/special/{
  special_count++
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: Terribly sorry realized later i have /'s that affect the code

Comment: @goosegoose, sorry I didn't get it; if your string is not `words` then change it in my code to `word`?